# Installing/Compiling NASM package on Mac OS X Maverick

Tags: macos, assembly, compilation, nasm

I have downloaded the Mac OS X NASM Assembler package from the NASM website and followed the instructions.

These are the instructions: NASM is an auto−configuring package: once you’ve unpacked it, cd to the directory it’s been unpacked into and type `./configure`. This shell script will find the best C compiler to use for building NASM and set up Makefiles accordingly.

When I do exactly that I get the error `No such file or directory.` Has anyone seen and solved this problem?  I have seen similar posts but they do not contain an answer. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you installed XCode and the Command Line Tools?

Comment: Is "configure" there? If not, you might try "autoconf" first. You're not "supposed" to have to do that, I don't think...

Comment: Thank you for all your responses but I am an idiot I didn't realize Xcode installs NASM automatically... hehe

Comment: Huh? That's isn't `nasm`, that's `as`, which is probably the GNU assembler (I haven't checked - perhaps the LLVM assembler).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My stock answer for these types of question is "use [macports](http://macports.org)":

After installation, it's as simple as:

```
$ sudo port install nasm
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the NASM bundled with Xcode.

```
 which nasm
/usr/bin/nasm
```